# Reset Path for iOS cover

Tags: iphone, applications

I've recently started using Path for iOS. I changed the Cover image used, the one behind the activity, but how on earth can I reset it back to what it was when I downloaded the app, I can only now choose from my photo library.

Comment: Did you check documentation or contact support yet?

Comment: I have the same problem: I tried to find the pictures within the iPhone file structure, but I couldn't find it. Deleting the app and after reinstalling setting up a new 'path' works though. Can anyone think of another way of getting those awesome pictures? What's the name of the photographer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. They say this in [their documentation](http://service.path.com/customer/portal/articles/257544-how-do-i-change-my-path-cover-photo-). They also say you can choose other images from the photographer who provided their stock cover art, but in fact you can't; you can leave the default image, change to one of your own, then change to another of your own, but that's all.

> Once you change your initial cover photo, you cannot change it back to the original default cover, but you can change it to any other photo that you take or store in your photo library.

I think this new version of Path is quite nice, but there are some rough edges, and you just bumped into one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to download nice Retina wallpapers for your iPhone and use it for your cover photo. Path doesn't (at least not in a very obvious way) lower the quality of photos uploaded to it. You can also check out fiftyfootshadows.net -- this is the person's blog who took the default cover photos of Path.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how this will solve the problem stated in the question (namely restoring the original set of wallpapers)?